# I got an error on Node js modules?

Tags: node.js

I am starting to learn node.js. I have a problem with modules. I copied and pasted the code from node.js docs but still got an error.

### module.js File

```
/* ----------------------Addition Calculation-------------------- */

const object = require('./lib.js');

console.log(`The sum of 25 and 456 is  + ${object.calculate1(25, 456)}`);

console.log(`The multipication of 25 and 2 is ${object.multiClass(25, 2)}`);

/* --------------------Circle Area Calculation-------------------- */

console.log(`The area of a circle of radius 7 is ${object.area(7)}`);

console.log(`The circumference of a circle of radius 7 is ${object.circumference(7)}`);

/* ----------------------Square Calculation-------------------- */

console.log(`The area of my square is ${object(2).area()}`);
```

### lib.js File

```
const { PI } = Math;

exports.calculate1 = (a, b) => a + b;

exports.multiClass = (a, b) => a * b;

exports.area = r => PI * r ** 2;

exports.circumference = r => 2 * PI * r;

exports = (width) => {
    return {
        area: () => width ** 2
    };
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you copy the error you got?

Comment: looks like you have redefined `exports` at the bottom of lib.js - so none of the other  functions you created exist anymore - i expect the error you're getting is something like "object.calculate is not a function" or is undefined or similar

Comment: Paste the error message here.

Comment: you r right #Robbie

Comment: thanks @Robbie for give me suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes now i made

### modules.js File

```
const object = require('./lib.js');

/* ----------------------Square Calculation-------------------- */

console.log(`The area of my square is ${object(2).area2()}`);

/* ----------------------Addition Calculation-------------------- */

console.log(`The sum of 25 and 456 is ${object.calculate1(25, 456)}`);

console.log(`The multipication of 25 and 2 is ${object.multiClass(25, 2)}`);

/* --------------------Circle Area Calculation-------------------- */

console.log(`The area of a circle of radius 7 is ${object.area(7)}`);

console.log(`The circumference of a circle of radius 7 is ${object.circumference(7)}`);
```

### lib.js File

```
const { PI } = Math;

module.exports = width => {
  return {
    area2: () => width ** 2
  };
};

module.exports.calculate1 = (a, b) => a + b;

module.exports.multiClass = (a, b) => a * b;

module.exports.area = r => PI * r ** 2;

module.exports.circumference = r => 2 * PI * r;
```

Comment: it would probably be cleaner to change the first function to `module.exports.area2 = width => width ** 2` - but i guess it depends what you're trying to do

Comment: yeah, i expected as much - i figured the tutorial you're following might be doing it that way to make a point